# Why do I get module 'numpy' has no attribute 'json_normalize' when using pd.json_normalize()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a simple code that scrapes reviews from an app in Google Playstore.
The scrapping runs well and returns a json data. I decided to normalize it and get pandas dataframe.
All I keep getting is **module 'numpy' has no attribute 'json_normalize'**
Please I need help, all solutions I saw online have not worked. Below is my code

```
from google_play_scraper import app, Sort, reviews, reviews_all
import pandas as pd
import numpy as pd

reviews = reviews_all(
    'com.hikingproject.android',
    sleep_milliseconds=0, # defaults to 0
    lang='en', # defaults to 'en'
    country='NG', # defaults to 'us'
    sort=Sort.MOST_RELEVANT, # defaults to Sort.MOST_RELEVANT
    #filter_score_with=5 # defaults to None(means all score)
)

opay_data = pd.json_normalize(reviews)
opay_data.to_csv('opay.csv', index = None)

print(opay_data.head())
```

```
from google_play_scraper import app, Sort, reviews, reviews_all
import pandas as pd
import numpy as pd

reviews = reviews_all(
    'com.hikingproject.android',
    sleep_milliseconds=0, # defaults to 0
    lang='en', # defaults to 'en'
    country='NG', # defaults to 'us'
    sort=Sort.MOST_RELEVANT, # defaults to Sort.MOST_RELEVANT
    #filter_score_with=5 # defaults to None(means all score)
)

opay_data = pd.json_normalize(reviews)
opay_data.to_csv('opay.csv', index = None)

print(opay_data.head())
```

Comment: Because `numpy` has no such attribute. note, you assigned `numpy` to the variable `pd`

Answer (score 1):

Your renaming your pandas import as pd, then renaming numpy also as pd - as the numpy import is last, it is now pd instead of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as pd
```

change it to this (assuming you need to import numpy at all):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Comment: My bad.
Thank you for pointing out. I never looked in that direction. However, after correcting it, I got another error

opay_data = pd.json_normalize(reviews)

the above gave me this error

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable